# combine :first-line :before

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

it is possibile to combine the pseudo-element :first-line and :before? Actually I'd like to have a character before any line of a p except the first one. I try:

```
p:first-line:before{content:""}   
p:before{content:"["}
```

but it do not work.

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

It's not currently possible to chain them as you have, nor can I think of a way to append content to every line of a paragraph except the first with just CSS. Further, the `content` property is [only used](http://css-tricks.com/css-content/) with `:before` and `:after`.

See the section "Multiple Pseudo-elements" on http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp to see how you can effectively combine pseudo elements:

```css
p:first-letter {
    color:#ff0000;
    font-size:xx-large;
}
p:first-line {
    color:#0000ff;
    font-variant:small-caps;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to have two pseudo-elements in succession; both the [CSS 2.1 synta](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#selector-syntax)x and the [CSS3 syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selector-syntax) for selectors forbid that.

The W3C CSS Validator does not report `p:first-line:before` as an error, but this is a bug; I re-opened a [bug report](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=160) on this. (The bug is not triggered if the two-colon syntax `p::first-line::before` is used: the validator says “The pseudo-element ::first-line can't appear here in the context css21 [first-line::before]”.)

It would not help in this case even if the construct were valid and supported. Using `:before` on `:first-line` would be pointless, since inserting content at the start of the first line would be the same as inserting it at the start of the element.

And `p:before` means a pseudo-element at the start of the content of `p`, not at the start of each rendered line of `p`. It is not possible to insert a character at the start of each line of an element using CSS.